# react bootstrap multiselect default value

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap-multiselect for my project. I need to pass a default value to it before loading. Does react-bootstrap-multiselect have an API to pass a default selected value(s)?

```
<Multiselect
       onChange={this.handleMultiSelect}
       value={this.props.multiSelectData}
       data={this.props.multiSelectData}
       buttonWidth="10
       multiple
    />
```

I want to pass a dynamic value, which will depend on a user click.

Thanks

Comment: can you add the code for your multiselect? Also, how do you want to pass the default value, through some variable or by hard-coding it?

Comment: @Chris, can you help me achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there is an API for doing this. Try instead modifying them directly in the DOM. Can you post the element as it appears in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who comes across this question again:

```
<Form.Control as="select" multiple defaultValue={['FOO', 'BAR']}>
    <option>FOO</option>
    <option>NOT SELECTED</option>
    <option>BAR</option>
</Form.Control>
```

You can simply set an **array** as **defaultValue**.

In the example above **FOO** and **BAR** are selected.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, set the selected attribute to true for the "data" parameter (in your case, this is an array for the required element this.props.multiSelectData). An example can be found [at this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-multiselect).

An example of an array for the "data" parameter with a default value:

```
var mass = [
    {
        value: -777, 
        label: 'No data', 
        selected: true
    }, 
    {
        value: 888, 
        label: 'data 888'
    }
]
```